# Thread is passing same Request Body multiple times. JSR223 PreProcessor is used to generate random request body every time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jsr223

My test has 2 API requests.
The parameters passed in 2nd API request body are to be unique every time. So I used JSR223 PreProcessor with groovy to generate that using RandomUtils.
The Thread group is set to have 3 threads with 15 sec Ramp up time and used Loop Controller with Loop count as 10. 1st API is in thread group and 2nd API is in Loop Controller as it needs to run multiple times.
But during test execution, for 2nd API one thread is passing same request body with same parameters multiple times. Because of which the test fails. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to state "how is that possible" without seeing your Groovy code.

The most common mistake is using [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75331085/xpath-assertion-vs-response-assertion-for-testing-soap-api-responses-in-jmeter/75332193#75332193) in Groovy scripts. As per [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, **ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.

If this is your case - refactor your code to use [`vars` shorthand for JMeterVariables class instance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) instead of JMeter Functions or Variables syntax and it should resolve your issue.