# XPath assertion vs Response Assertion for testing SOAP API responses in Jmeter

Tags: testing, soap, jmeter

Which one's better in terms of testing properly as well as speed? I've read somewhere that Xpath Assertion takes more memory and CPU

Answer (score 0):

It  depends on the nature of your response, its size, the criteria you need to assert and their complexity.

For example if you're looking for the presence of a single word - the Response Assertion would work just fine.

But in case if you need to validate an attribute of a node which has parent attribute equal to something - coming up with a proper regular expression would be either impossible or at least very hard.

So if you can accomplish your requirement using Response Assertion - go for it.

You can additionally measure execution speed and resource consumption by using a [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) and see how many requests JMeter can handle and how much CPU it takes like it's described in [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor)

[XPath2 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Assertion) is better than XPath Assertion given your response is a valid XML.